# One-sided vs two-sided hypothesis testing - Should the hypothesis reflect this?

Tags: writing, data, stem

I had written a hypothesis that we expect *x* outcome variable to increase when *y* treatment is applied. A reviewer commented that based off of the hypothesis, we should be doing a one-sided test.

However, this doesn't make sense to me, since it is important to know from the data if x actually decreases when y is applied. Wouldn't doing a one-way hypothesis miss this?

If the written hypothesis must reflect what kind of testing was done, how should it be written to prevent it being boring/uninformative? For example, "We expected *x* would change when *y* is applied".

Thank you!

Comment: @EdV I think that this is sufficiently divorced from the contents of the OP's research to be on-topic. Its relevant for anyone whose research involves hypothesis testing.

Comment: @nick012000 Good to know: the boundary between on topic and off seems to be fractal. Anyway, Buffy’s answer is correct and the choice of one sided or two sided gets done before the testing.

Comment: This is probably on-topic on crossvalidated.stackexchange.com I don't think it's on-topic here, as it is fairly technical and substantive.

Comment: I was interested in the writing aspect - how to write the hypothesis at the end of the introduction. However, from Buffy's answer I see that I was missing the connection between the hypothesis I set out at the beginning and how it's written up.

Comment: This is opinion based.  Even if we knew exactly what the research was, it might still be opinion based.  I do not see any reason not to do it the reviewer's way.

Answer (score 3):

If your hypothesis doesn't match your test, how can you say that carrying out the experiment gives you anything valid. Make them match. If you want a two sided hypothesis, use a two sided test. Similarly for one sided.

Of course, a close examination of the data might reveal whether the preponderance is on the high or low side, but that isn't really using statistics correctly.

Make them match. If you expect an increase, then test for that. If the test fails then reevaluate your assumptions and test again.

Comment: Right. To echo: claiming to be testing for several possibilities all at once is like p-value hacking and such: a mis-use of statistics.

Comment: Thank you - this clarifies things for me. I think I missed the connection between the hypothesis I set out with and then what gets written in the manuscript. I appreciate the clarification!

Comment: @paulgarrett People get very agitated about P-hacking, but thinking about it from a Bayesian perspective, I'd expect the effect of P-hacking on the inference process to be fairly weak - specifically, I'd expect the number of data points required to reach a given level of certainty to scale like the logarithm of the number of hypotheses being considered.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DanielHatton, I think you're right, but/and people operating in ignorance of such considerations have a big chance of messing up... Awareness of the pitfalls, I think, is important, and not reliably "publicized", it seems.

Comment: @DanielHatton For one thing, I think p-hacking often implies not including all the relevant data in the analysis, which is a major problem for a Bayesian. Anyway, on the inference side, I would say that the Bayesian way to compare hypotheses is to construct odds ratios. If you try N hypotheses that you consider to have equal prior odds, then the log odds is just the difference in the log evidences for each hypothesis. With p-hacking, you end up with N hypotheses that don't really have equal *prior* odds, but were chosen after looking at the data, and on top of that you only keep 1.

Comment: In other words... say we use p-hacking to confirm hypothesis H', which we claim in a paper was a good fit to some data. If we did a true Bayesian analysis, the honest way to confirm H would be to have decided on hypotheses H1, H2, ... HN, H' to test, and assigned prior odds to each one, then we do a measurement and compute odds ratios for each pair. But if we look at the data before formulating the hypotheses, this invalidates the whole procedure. This is a big problem if, before we looked at the data, we would have assigned H' a much smaller prior odds, than we did after looking at the data.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, omitting part of the data set would be deeply problematic, as would allowing information from the data set to leak into the prior (either the prior between hypotheses or the prior over adjustable parameters within any one of the hypotheses) (although formulating hypotheses after seeing the data does not necessarily imply that one is guilty of such information leakage).

Comment: True -- although I think the problem with p-hacking is that you end up using an analysis procedure / hypothesis that *in advance* you would have said was contrived (with low prior odds), but that you suddenly after the fact treat as having high prior odds *because that hypothesis has a numerically large value of the evidence.* So, it is cheating to get the answer you want. OTOH I agree if you do everything honestly, there is not really a way to "p-hack" as a Bayesian; if some weird hypothesis has enough evidence from the data to support it, then that may well be the right conclusion.